# Errors seen when setting up logspout in Hyperledger fabric 2.2

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Following steps described here to setup logspout:
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/deploy_chaincode.html

### Running this produces below errors:
./monitordocker.sh net_test
Starting monitoring on all containers on the network net_test
xxxx
docker: Error response from daemon: network net_test not found.
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8000: Connection refused

### xxx@xxxx:/home/fabric/fabric-samples/test-network#
xxx@xxxx:/home/fabric/fabric-samples/test-network# ./monitordocker.sh
Starting monitoring on all containers on the network basicnetwork_basic
xxxx
docker: Error response from daemon: network basicnetwork_basic not found.
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8000: Connection refused

xxx@xxxx:/home/fabric/fabric-samples/test-network#
xxxx@xxxx:/home/fabric/fabric-samples/test-network# ./monitordocker.sh net_basic
Starting monitoring on all containers on the network net_basic
xxxx
docker: Error response from daemon: network net_basic not found.
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8000: Connection refused

Few questions:

1. there is no process running in default port 8000. So connection refused error is expected. Do we need to use any other port ?
2. what is the name of the network to be given when running monitordocker.sh ?

Any other troubleshooting info is appreciated.

Comment: I think "127.0.0.1 port 8000: Connection refused" says it all.

Comment: My bad, I should have added bit more context. In this case, from what I understand,  monitordocker.sh is using logspout to route log messages. I am able to see docker container for /bin/logsput is running after executing of monitordocker.sh script. But it is not listening on any particular port. So curl command output "Connection refused" is expected. My question here is what port number needs to be used when running the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, found the issue. The network name is fabric_test. So I issued command like
./monitordocker.sh fabric_test

This resolved the problem.

Comment: The network name has changed again. Command:
  `./network.sh up createChannel`
creates default called:
`net_test`